# Is there an infinite ring having finitely many zero divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am looking for an example of an infinite ring having finitely many zero divisors. Is that possible?  If there is such ring please give a hint.

Comment: What is a finite zero divisor? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: «finitely many zero divisors» is what is probably meant.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: It is "finitely many zero divisors".

Comment: If that's what you meant, then that is the right way to phrase it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: . . . or one could say "only a finite number of zero divisors". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The ring of integers has no zero divisor. Does it count as an example ?

Comment: @Peter: No. It does not count.

Comment: Then you should add that at least one zero divisor is required.

Comment: Or perhaps at least two.  (Arguably, zero is a zero-divisor in a nontrivial ring.)

Comment: Per definition, $0$ does not count as a zero divisor.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Is right to ask the following question. For each natural number n, is it possible to find an infinite ring having precisely n zero divisors?

Comment: @Peter: That depends on your definition. :-) There's no universal agreement.  (But the theorems in commutative algebra tend to be neater if you count zero as a zero-divisor.)

Comment: @spohreis : If you mean is the language right, I think so. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So true. For instance the well known fact, that the natural ring map $R \to S^{-1}R$ is injective iff $S$ does not contain a zero-divisor. I would hate to state that, when you do not count zero as a zero-divisor :)